# Construct a TM to show that {<G,s,t,k> | G is a directed graph with path length $\le$ k from s to t} is in class P

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, turing-machines, np-complete

I would like to construct a deterministic TM that decides $L=${$<G,s,t,k>$ | $G$ is a directed graph that has a path of length at most $k$ from vertex $s$ to vertex $t$} in polynomial time.

So far, my construction is as follows.

$M=$"On input $<G,s,t,k>:$

1. For each path $p$ from $s$ to a vertex $v \in G$ of $k$ length:

------1.0 Clear all marks from vertices in $G$.

------1.1 Mark the vertices in $p$.

------1.2 Scan input. If $t$ is marked, accept.

2. Reject, since $t$ is not within $k$ steps from $s$."

(1.0), (1.1), and (1.2) are each $O(n)$, and $(2)$ is $O(1)$.

However, I think (1) is $O(n!)$.

What is a better approach that would make this $O(n^m)$ (i.e., polynomial)?

Edit:

The TM does not have to be "rigorously made".

For example, to find determine whether PATH={<G,s,t>| G is a directed graph that has a path from s to t} is in $P$, the following TM is acceptable:

M="On input <G,s,t>"

1. Mark vertex s.
2. Repeat until no additional vertex is marked:

------Scan all edges of G. If there is an edge from a marked vertex u to an unmarked vertex v, mark v.

3. If t is marked, accept. Otherwise, reject."

((1) is $O(1)$, (2) is $O(\#$of edges $*\#$of vertices$)=O(n^2*n=n^3)$, and (3) is $O(1)$).

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you really want to have an explicit Turing machine (with states and transitions an stuff) or do you rather want to have a (polynomial time) algorithm? Regarding computability they are of cause equivalent, but the former is way more complicated to write down and requires you to specify the specs of your TM (singletape, multitape etc) and how you encode graphs...

Comment: @PrudiiArca, I've added a sample TM in an edit. You could take a look.
Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Given a sequence of vertices $(s, v_1, \ldots, v_m, t)$, where $0 \leq m \leq k-1$, how many operations does it take to decide whether the sequence defines a path in $G$? How many such sequences are there?

Comment: Wouldn't checking a particular sequence be $O(n)$? But wouldn't going through all sequences be $O(n!)$? We have to order m of the k vertices.

Comment: Let $n$ be the number of vertices. If checking a given sequence takes $k$ operations and you have roughly $n^{k-2}$, sequences, then you need roughly $k n^{k-2}$ operations. If $k$ is fixed and $n\to\infty$, I guess you write this as $O(n^{k-2})$.

Comment: Oh, I see. If I am understanding this correctly, since k (and thus k-2) is fixed, $n^{k-2}$ is polynomial, and not "factorial". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial time algorithm is for example a slightly modified breadth first search:

Start with $s$ and consider all neighbors. Then consider all the neighbor‘s neighbors etc. up to level $k$. If you found $t$ along the way (you might as well stop the algorithm in this situation) the graph $G$ is in your class, otherwise not.

If $\Delta$ denotes the maximal outgoing degree of $G$ this algorithm has a runtime bounded by $\Delta + \Delta^2 + ... + \Delta^k$ hence is in $\mathcal{O}(\Delta^k)$. This is of cause polynomial in the number of vertices $n$, the number of edges $m$ and the maximal degree $\Delta$, but it is exponential in $k$.

Comment: Since k is fixed, it would be polynomial, right?

Comment: Well it doesn’t seem to be fixed, as it is part of the data... If $k$ does not vary within the definition of $L$ the algorithm is indeed polynomial, but if you allow it to vary the algorithm is only polynomial in the graph, but not in $k$ anymore...

Comment: Could we move this to chat? I think I added you to a chat room already.